# Python data structure for specific storage

Tags: python

plz help me find the best solution to store data in python. For example there are a lot of humans and every human has phone number, id, book. I need to make an array of those humans. How do I organise it so that name of human is the key ?

Comment: it must be an array of key : value,value,value

Comment: keep human name as key for dictionary and rest of the vlaues like number.id,books as a list to the each key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really depend on your data(size, cols and so on...)

A nice option is a `list` of `dicts`:

```
my_data = [{"Name":"John","Age":15}, {"Name":"Bob","Age":16}]
print my_data[0]['Name']
print my_data[0]['Age']
print my_data[1]['Name']
print my_data[1]['Age']
```

Output:

```
John
15
Bob
16
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary in this way

```
d = {}
d[name] = [v1, v2, v2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Store data in dictionary, like that:

```
human_data = {
   'john': {
        'id': 1,
        'phone_number': '666333'
    }
}
```

If you want to save that data (persist it), then you can store it in file or database:

```
import json

with open('file.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(human_data, f)
```